# Android Packaging: Error generating final archive resources.ap_

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, apk

I'm currently trying to build a PhoneGap project I've been working on in Eclipse. However, when I try to build and run the project on the Android Emulator, I get the following error...

`Error generating final archive: Failed to add 
/Users/me/Projects/MyApp/bin/resources.ap_ Unknown Android Packaging Problem`

I've cleaned the project several times, removed the resources.ap_ file, as well as the contents of the gen directory.

Anything else I can try? Much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.app.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyApp_AndroidActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter> </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Your application haven't even ran once?If yes then can you share your Android.xml file

Comment: @Coder_sLaY Here you go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix found. Turns out I had a tar file in my assets folder that I had left there by mistake. Removing it worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your manifest file does not have a starting application tag.Its a typo maybe..
Correct that.Secondly
Try adding the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
```

Add then let me know whether it works

Comment: Thanks for the help, turns out that I had a tar file in my assets directory. Removing it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an image resource file with name like "some_resource_name Copy". Build goes well, but on launch this error appeared.

Answer (score -1):

add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

after

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to manifest file.

Comment: please learn how to format code (each line needs 4 leading spaces)  - without seeing that code, the remaining text doesn't make much sense :-)